# How do I partition data in a column table in SnappyData?

Tags: snappydata

I am unable to figure out the syntax to partition my 'column' table.  Here is an example that fails on me as well as many variations on it.

```
CREATE TABLE SENSOR_DATA_COL_BY_YEAR USING column OPTIONS(PARTITION_BY year_num, buckets '11') AS (SELECT sensor_id,metric,collection_time,value,sensor_time,year AS year_num, month AS month_num from STAGING_1);
```

And... the error.

> ERROR 38000: (SQLState=38000 Severity=-1)
>   (Server=172.31.8.115[1528],Thread[DRDAConnThread_34,5,gemfirexd.daemons])
>   The exception 'Invalid input 'C', expected dmlOperation, insert,
>   withIdentifier, select or put (line 1, column 1): CREATE TABLE
>   SENSOR_DATA_COL_BY_YEAR USING column OPTIONS(PARTITION_BY
>   year_num, buckets '11') AS (SELECT
>   sensor_id,metric,collection_time,value,sensor_time,year AS year_num,
>   month AS month_num from STAGING_1) ^;' was thrown while evaluating an
>   expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

column name specified in PARTITION_BY clause should be in quotes "year_num"

modified query:

CREATE TABLE SENSOR_DATA_COL_BY_YEAR USING column OPTIONS(PARTITION_BY "year_num", buckets '11') AS (SELECT sensor_id,metric,collection_time,value,sensor_time,year AS year_num, month AS month_num from STAGING_1);

Comment: This worked for one column.  Now... when I try to partition on both year_num and month_num, but no syntax I've tried works.  Does this syntax support multiple partition columns and if so, what does that look like?

Comment: The syntax for multi column partition by clause is PARTITION_BY 'year_num,sensor_id'. i.e comma separated column names in quotes.